# VLC module to control audio and video speed separately

Tags: c++, c, module, vlc

I want the VLC to run video and audio at different speeds, and synchronize them at a given point (as an input).
I have two ways to that:

1. Build two new modules which control respectively the audio and video separately, so I don't need to "go throw" all source code. It seems to be a hard solution, because we would have to write and re-write big pieces of code that already appear in VLC. The question is how to build these modules and what do we need to control to do it.
2. Enter the code and add pieces of code where VLC passes the audio and video frames to the buffers - I searched for this point a lot of time and I didn't find it. If someone know where this point it will help me a lot.

Comment: I don't understand this. you want to do this by writing code or by not writing code?

Comment: I guess the VLC community will likely prefer a separate module. Could you give more details maybe in the sense of a use case? Is this intended to synchronize a camera with audio in order to restream them?
Have you looked at VLC's developer guide wiki? Specifically this page on how to write modules: https://wiki.videolan.org/Hacker_Guide/How_To_Write_a_Module/ 
Then look into the directories in the VLC's git such as around here: http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=tree;f=modules/access;h=a95aa7655ac68a5f0a130ab55c0327da09d81f27;hb=ddba52206f69bb123bea8ed4d4ada07b3cb1223c

Comment: Here are two use cases of what I need: 1. Assume that we have a video of a lecture, which includes some parts of white board and the lecturer writes on it, and other parts that the lecturer talks. When the lecturer writes on the board, we may prefer to make the video slower and the audio still at the same speed, and at the end to synchronize video and audio. At other parts we prefer to make the video and audio faster (maybe with different rates or the same).

Comment: 2. When we watch news on TV, we always notice that when the reporter is at different place which is far from the studio (e.g. the studio is at the US and the reporter is at China), we see that the video is not synchronized with the audio - the man is in studio talks and after a period of time the reporter response. We want to hide these issues by delaying & synchronizing video and audio at different speeds and delays.